# Angular CLI build file size output shown not matching with actual on disk

Tags: angularjs, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am using Angular CLI (1.2.6) and Angular(4.3.2) and running following command

**ng serve --aot --prod  --proxy-config config/proxy.config.json**

Or

**ng build --aot --prod  --proxy-config config/proxy.config.json**

If you see below output **vendor.**.bundle.js** showing **4.59 MB** But if I  open dist folder and check, its showing me **1.47 MB** on disk.

So likewise for

1. vendor.**.bundle.js - showing(4.59 MB), on disk (1.47 MB)
2. main.**.bundle.js - showing(1.89MB), on disk (870KB)

So want to know, why this has difference ?

```
[HPM] Subscribed to http-proxy events:  [ 'error', 'close' ]
Hash: c030f10843de67c2fe52
Time: 145608ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.cf0c1911723ba2bc9e0d.bundle.js (polyfills) 253 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.56a2048fe2f1df9b3bfb.bundle.js (main) 1.89 MB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.dcf18dcb7e819103f605.bundle.css (styles) 228 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.ae04ef2adeac9f77347c.bundle.js (vendor) 4.59 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.7a0ff2515f1bf65b1641.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asset size fix was made and is part of release 1.3.0 (currently RC)

Look for this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.0-rc.0) which will link to [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/61b4e22)

```
@angular/cli: rewrite stats output to properly show the asset size
```

Comment: Yes, checked with version 1.3.0, it's showing properly.